# Visual Studio code Intellisense not working on NPM package

Tags: visual-studio-code

Intellisense is not working for npm packages

I have installed validator package.

The Intellisense is not showing any functions

[image]

Intellisense works only when I type like this

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can use jsdoc.

```js
/**
 * @type {import('validator').default} validator
 */
const validator = require('validator');
```